# What would cause broken <input> elements that don't show text in this template?

Tags: cross-browser, browser-support, user-input

I'm building a web page by modifying this template:
http://webthemez.com/preview/?doctor-free-responsive-website-template/

At the bottom, in the Contact area, there are two `<input>`s and one `<textarea>`. The inputs only work in Opera. No other browser lets me edit the text or even displays the placeholder.

I can't figure out where the problem is. The HTML? The CSS? The JavaScript?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the padding specified by CSS along with a fixed height.   The box is not tall enough to contain both the text and the white space padding.

```
.form-control {
    padding: 22px 4px;
    height: 34px;
}
```

The best way to discover this problem is to use developer tools.   I use Firefox and right click to "inspect element".   From that I can check and uncheck the CSS rules to see which one is causing the problem:

[image]

When I uncheck those rules I see the text I entered:

[image]

Comment: So it's in the bootstrap code? What can I do if I use a bootstrap CDN?

Comment: I'm not sure what bootstrap code is, sorry.